# Deploy webservice on a remote server

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest

I have created a REST web-service on .net. Now I want to deploy it on a server. How to do it. Also the server doesn't have visual studio but I don't think that's going to be a problem RIGHT??
Basically I want to access the web-service over internet.

PS: This is my very first web service creation. I have read many articles and got quite a bit confused.

Comment: What have you used to create the service? MVC, WCF...? Which bit of the deployment are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)?

Depending on the service type you may have [more options](http://forums.iis.net/t/1187686.aspx/1) available to you!